# bundle install not completing due to puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and I was using cloud9 ide till now. I decided to install rails locally on my windows 8.1 system. I installed rails using the Railsinstaller. I also installed Aptana Studio 3. Then I cloned my repository. Everything worked fine till now. Now when I give the command `bundle install` I get the following error -

```
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.7.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.2.2
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile 0.6.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.6.2
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.6
Using loofah 2.0.2
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
Using actionview 4.2.2
Using rack 1.6.4
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.2.2
Using globalid 0.3.5
Using activejob 4.2.2
Using mime-types 2.6.1
Using mail 2.6.3
Using actionmailer 4.2.2
Using activemodel 4.2.2
Using arel 6.0.0
Using activerecord 4.2.2
Using ansi 1.5.0
Using bcrypt 3.1.7
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.3.pre1
Using sass 3.4.14
Using bootstrap-sass 3.2.0.0
Using will_paginate 3.0.7
Using bootstrap-will_paginate 0.0.10
Using bundler 1.7.7
Using columnize 0.9.0
Using debugger-linecache 1.2.0
Using slop 3.6.0
Using byebug 3.4.0
Using hitimes 1.2.2
Using timers 4.0.1
Using celluloid 0.16.0
Using coderay 1.1.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
Using execjs 2.5.2
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.2.2
Using coffee-rails 4.1.0
Using faker 1.4.2
Using ffi 1.9.8
Using formatador 0.2.5
Using rb-fsevent 0.9.5
Using rb-inotify 0.9.5
Using listen 2.10.1
Using lumberjack 1.0.9
Using nenv 0.2.0
Using shellany 0.0.1
Using notiffany 0.0.6
Using method_source 0.8.2
Using win32console 1.3.2
Using pry 0.10.1
Using guard 2.12.6
Using guard-minitest 2.3.1
Using multi_json 1.11.1
Using jbuilder 2.2.3
Using jquery-rails 4.0.3
Using sprockets 3.2.0
Using sprockets-rails 2.3.1
Using rails 4.2.2
Using mini_backtrace 0.1.3
Using ruby-progressbar 1.7.5
Using minitest-reporters 1.0.5
Using pg 0.17.1

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for BIO_read() in -lcrypto... no
checking for BIO_read() in -llibeay32... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby
        --with-puma_http11-dir
        --without-puma_http11-dir
        --with-puma_http11-include
        --without-puma_http11-include=${puma_http11-dir}/include
        --with-puma_http11-lib
        --without-puma_http11-lib=${puma_http11-dir}/lib
        --with-cryptolib
        --without-cryptolib
        --with-libeay32lib
        --without-libeay32lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.11.1 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/puma-2.11.1/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing puma (2.11.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install puma -v '2.11.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Then I tried giving `gem install puma -v '2.11.1`, I got -

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing puma:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for BIO_read() in -lcrypto... no
checking for BIO_read() in -llibeay32... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby
        --with-puma_http11-dir
        --without-puma_http11-dir
        --with-puma_http11-include
        --without-puma_http11-include=${puma_http11-dir}/include
        --with-puma_http11-lib
        --without-puma_http11-lib=${puma_http11-dir}/lib
        --with-cryptolib
        --without-cryptolib
        --with-libeay32lib
        --without-libeay32lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.11.3 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/puma-2.11.3/gem_make.out
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a difference x86 and 64-bit.

Your windows is 64-bit?